# Qual è la frase corretta?

Tags: grammar, phrase-choice

Quale tra queste frasi è quella corretta o preferibile? Perché?

> - Gli adolescenti hanno sempre bisogno di avere adulti accanto.
> - Gli adolescenti hanno sempre bisogno di avere degli adulti accanto.
> - Gli adolescenti hanno sempre bisogno di avere accanto adulti.
> - Gli adolescenti hanno sempre bisogno di avere accanto degli adulti.

Answer (score 3):

Il "degli" è un partitivo, che in questo esempio fa la funzione di articolo indeterminativo plurale (in spagnolo e in catalano il partitivo non c'è, ma in compenso in queste lingue esistono dei veri articoli indeterminativi plurali - unos, unas, uns, unes - che l'italiano invece non ha).

Se usato al singolare, abbiamo la vera e propria funzione originale di "partitivo" (una parte di) come viene usato in francese, ad esempio "ho bevuto dell'acqua".

Le opinioni sul partitivo sono discordanti, però certamente si usa moltissimo nel parlato. Nello scritto ci sono contesti in cui risulta un po' pesante, soprattutto quando appare accompagnato da preposizioni:

> **Si è messo in dei brutti giri**
>
> **Si è salvato con degli ingegnosi stratagemmi**

A volte è proprio decisamente da evitare (per non dire sbagliato):

> **Venivano da delle terre lontane**    # No, anche se non mi stupirebbe sentirlo nel parlato
>
> **Mi ha parlato di dei libri interessanti***   # No, in nessun caso

In questi casi si può generalmente omettere del tutto:

> **Si è messo in brutti giri**
>
> **Venivano da terre lontane**

o riformulare la frase per usare "alcuni", "certi", "qualche" etc. ove possibile.

> **Si è salvato con alcuni ingegnosi stratagemmi**
>
> **Mi ha parlato di certi libri interessanti**

Nei tuoi esempi (tutti corretti) il "degli" sta da solo, quindi direi che non ci sono problemi ad usarlo. Il mio personale ordine di preferenza è 4, 2, 1, 3
 (la 3 effettivamente suona un po' insolita, dubito che si userebbe correntemente).

Answer (score 2):

Tutte e 4 le frasi sono corrette ma:

Adopererei la seconda e la quarta (in ordine di priorità indifferente)

La prima la userei con priorità inferiore alle due già specificate sopra, ed infine la terza eviterei di usarla perché per come è impostata esprime il concetto in modo più complesso.

Answer (score 0):

Sono tutte corrette.

Quelle con 'degli' appaiono un po' più enfatiche.

La terza non la userei.

:)